# Drop-down menu for Emacs

Tags: emacs

When I am using yasnippet for a keyword that has more than one choices it opens up a new buffer instead of dropdown menu. How do I configure emacs to display a dropdown menu? Please see this [cedet](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/intellisense.shtml) example for what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put `yas-dropdown-prompt` (or `yas-x-prompt`, if you want graphical menu like on cedet screenshots) at the first position in `yas-prompt-functions` variable, like this:

```lisp
(require 'dropdown-list) ;; this is a separate package, that needs to be installed
(setq yas-prompt-functions
      '(yas-dropdown-prompt
        yas-ido-prompt
        yas-x-prompt
        yas-completing-prompt
        yas-no-prompt))
```

Comment: + 1 Do you know how to do this for cedet as well? They have no documentation whatsoever.

Comment: @Mark: can't help with that, sorry.

Comment: As I remember, CEDET allows to specify which functions will be used to show completions - I don't remember name of variable, please run appropos...